# Ignore extra white space in Unity3D Texture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have different textures for a player's helmet, shirt and pants in order to render custom uniforms. They have white space so it lays on the model correctly, but this is causing the App's file size to be huge once installed because the game has over a hundred items and each texture is 2.7 MB.

How can I tell Unity to ignore parts of the image or map the textures onto the player so that I  do not need the white space? For example, cutting the whitespace out of the helmet image lowers the size to under a MB.

[image: Helmet]
[image]
[image: Pants]

Thanks!

Comment: there's a texture size option where you can set the min size of a texture when you select it

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't see how that helps in this scenario.

Comment: You mentioned these textures will be used for 3D models, yes? Why have you set up your UVs to waste so much texture data?

Comment: I don't know about the person who asked this question, but as I mention in my answer, sometimes models just "come like that". I've noticed it from time to time when procuring models for prototyping from certain stores, and even if it's just a place holder, the space wasted by these kinds of UV maps makes builds take longer than they should.

Comment: There is white space because that is where the other clothing items are. So the helmet does not fill the whole image because a shirt texture is laid over top.

Answer (score 1):

*For the sake of others who read this:*

The obvious answer is, cut out the empty spaces in an image editor. That will solve the problem in the way it really should be solved.

That being said, it's quite possible you are using poorly UV mapped models that need that space, and you are unable to fix this, as the person who asked this question is.

If you're in a position where it might cost a little time or money to get someone to fix it, you should, because no matter what, you're wasting space, and it will add up. No one wants a 100Mb download to get 50Mb worth of game. And if you payed someone for models and they came like this, consider taking it up with them, because this is a somewhat major flaw.

*The "real" answer:*

The first thing you should do is enable compression. From your picture it appears you are using the RGBA 16-bit format. This is a lower quality version of Truecolor, an uncompressed 32-bit format, but is not compressed in the "traditional" sense.

You should use the "Compressed" image import  setting (To see it you must turn off Advanced settings). This will select one of several compression formats (depending on the platform), all of which are highly optimized. You can define a specific compression in the Advanced window, but it is rarely needed, as Unity is great at choosing the right one for a given situation, and can can take special cases (such as specific chipsets) into consideration.

Depending on the compression algorithm, that white space could easily end up taking next to no space, and depending on the image, the compression might end up virtually undetectable.

On average the "Compressed" setting can create several orders of magnitude of a reduction of image size.

From there, if your image is still to large you can experiment with import size. This creates a fairly linear change in space taken and quality image. You are importing at 1024x1024 right now. Importing at 512x512 will about half the amount of space taken, and half the resolution of your image, but depending on the art style, the change can often be negligible visually.

You can for more details on these changes in the documentation for the [texture importer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)

Comment: The empty space is laid over the model as well, it is transparent because that is where the other clothing items are. So they are all using the same UV map so that they lay over correctly.